# django logout functionality doesnt appear to be destroying session

Tags: django, python-3.x, view

I have `urls.py`:

```
path(r'Logout/',views.Logout),
```

a `Logout` views.py:

```
def Logout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        logout(request)
        return render(request, 'logout_thankyou.html', {})
```

`templates/logout_thankyou.html` as:

```
<h1>Log out</h1>
<h3>You've been successfully logged out.</h3>
```

Why is this throwing an error of:

```
views.Logout didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the request is not a POST.

If you don't want to have to submit a form in order to logout, you should remove that if statement.